# How do I horizontally center a checkbox in its parent in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like this checkbox to

1. Not have content
2. Be horizontally centered in its parent

However, I can't get the checkbox to float in the center. Is there a way to do this?

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Background="LightBlue">
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>            
    </StackPanel>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me.

```
<StackPanel Width="100" Background="LightBlue">
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You're right. It looks like I was inadvertently inheriting padding and MinHeight from a style. Visual studio helped me find those inherited values.